# Update the lowest (as it were) empty column

Tags: sql, oracle

In my OracleDB, there is a table with 100 columns (1-100). I would need a query to update the lowest empty one with value (e.g. 1) and cannot figure it out on my own. How to always get the lowest empty column (e.g. Column 11 if columns 1-10 are not empty)?

Would  appreciate any help.

Comment: What RDBMS (MySql, SQL Server, Oracle...)? And how does your table schema looks like?

Comment: +1 I think its a Good Question asked Here. Don't know why Downvote. I think other then Table Structure there is nothing for Downvote.

Answer (score 0):

It's brutal but it should work. Try

```
UPDATE Table1
   SET column1 = (CASE WHEN column1 IS NULL THEN 'new value' ELSE column1 END),
       column2 = (CASE WHEN column1 IS NOT NULL 
                        AND column2 IS NULL THEN 'new value' ELSE column2 END),
       column3 = (CASE WHEN column2 IS NOT NULL 
                        AND column3 IS NULL THEN 'new value' ELSE column3 END),
       column4 = (CASE WHEN column3 IS NOT NULL 
                        AND column4 IS NULL THEN 'new value' ELSE column4 END),
       column5 = (CASE WHEN column4 IS NOT NULL 
                        AND column5 IS NULL THEN 'new value' ELSE column5 END)
       ...
WHERE id = 1
```

Note: The possible drawback apart from the length of the query is that every column will be updated.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/be659/1)** demo

Comment: Well for 100 columns? Could I not use some kind of cycle?

Comment: @KhDonen Well, yes. Only with dynamic SQL I believe. The root of your problem is in poor schema design. Your question suggests that these columns should be rows in a separate table that you could've easily joined and  achieved your goal with no pain at all.